# How to remove extra spacing between lines using NPOI

Tags: c#, ms-word, npoi, xwpf

I'm a new developer and need your help

I'm using NPOI to create word documents based on txt files. Already have an word example and the format is ok.

As you can see in this image, the space between lines is narrow :

[Image without spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIccj.png)

After I created the Word document using NPOI, the new file has more spacing between paragraphs:

[Image with Spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we9Du.png)

Every time I added a new text into the word document, I set this :

```html
     private static void SetParagraphRunSettings(XWPFRun paragraphRun)
        {
            paragraphRun.FontSize = 7;
            paragraphRun.FontFamily = "Courier New";
            paragraphRun.IsBold = true;
        }
        
        private static void SetParagraphSettings(XWPFParagraph paragraph, string stepComment)
        {
            if (stepComment.Contains("Landscate -"))
            {
                paragraph.IndentationFirstLine = 0;
                paragraph.FirstLineIndent = 0;
                paragraph.IndentationLeft = 1; //(int)(0.002 * 20); // 0.64 Cm = 0.002 inches
                paragraph.IndentationHanging = 1;  //(int)(0.002 * 20); // 0.64 Cm = 0.002 inches
            }
            paragraph.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.LEFT;
            paragraph.IndentationRight = 0;
            paragraph.SpacingBefore = 0;
            paragraph.SpacingAfter = 0;
            // Line Spcing = Sigle 
            paragraph.setSpacingBetween(1, LineSpacingRule.AUTO);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you create an issue in https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi-examples/issues? I'd like to check if this is a bug of the latest NPOI.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.  I reckon it converts simple lines into paragraphs.